# How to get box-shadow programmatically under Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cross-browser, opera

With jQuery, i'm trying to do

```
item.css("-o-box-shadow")
```

or:

```
item.css("box-shadow")
```

... but getting empty string.

Under Webkit and Gecko it works, using "-webkit" and "-moz" prefixes.

How to do it under Opera ?

I've also tried "boxShadow", but again, getting empty string.

```
$(".flag").css("boxShadow", "rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 4pt 4pt 7pt"); // i see, it was set
$(".flag").css("boxShadow"); // returns ""
```

Comment: If anybody thinks they've solved this, please provide an example where you *retrieve* the `box-shadow` property which was set via CSS.

Answer (score 3):

$('div').css('boxShadow','10px 10px 10px #FF00FF');

so: .css('boxShadow');

Comment: It does't works. When i set shadow in this way, i see, it was applied, but i get empty string, doing .css("boxShadow")

Answer (score 2):

After searching and trying for the last fifteen minutes, I think Opera has a bug.

You just can't retrieve the `box-shadow` value, unless there's some obscure undocumented way.

Answer (score 2):

this sounds like an issue with the way Opera has implemented boxShadow. i will see what i can dig up about why that value isn't available.

in the meantime, using your example, i think you can retrieve the entire style using `$(".flag").attr("style")` then split the string on the ':'.

Comment: setting the whole style object sounds like it may be a good workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you want to use jQuery you can use this:

```
$('.item').css('boxShadow','5px 5px 6px #333333');
```

[Example here for you](http://jsfiddle.net/BWWvn/) :) (open in Opera)

Comment: You do realise that this isn't what the OP is asking? See my comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a bug in Opera. jQuery's .css() method uses `getComputedStyle || currentStyle` to return CSS properties, both of which return the empty string for `boxShadow`.